# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre JQuery, JQueryUI y JQueryMobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Luego de trabajar un poco con JQuery, me dí cuenta que existen otras versiones de JQuery como, JQueryUI y JQueryMobile indirectamente las he estado usando para la aplicación que estoy trabajando, pero luego de googlear un poco **no entiendo bien cual es la diferencia de estas 3 versiones**, o los problemas que buscan solucionar cada una.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery es una biblioteca JavaScript que actúa en el DOM (incluyendo HTML y CSS).

jQuery UI es un complemento de jQuery creado para hacer más simple la integración de componentes de interfaces como sliders, tabs, botones, drag n drop, etc.

jQuery mobile como su nombre lo sugiere está enfocado en ayudar a generar rápidamente interfaces web para dispositivos móviles. También es un complemento de jQuery, aunque no funciona con las versiones más recientes (al menos hasta este momento).

---

A continuación daré una pequeña opinión (lo más objetiva posible) sobre el uso de estas bibliotecas:

Si bien jQuery podía ser muy útil hace unos años para acceder elementos del DOM fácilmente, con ES2015+ considero que ya no es necesario incluir una biblioteca como jQuery para esto.

jQuery UI puede aún ser útil para proyectos rápidos o para pruebas de concepto, el problema es que es una dependencia "grande" en términos de tamaño y la deuda tecnológica generada por usar un conjunto de herramientas así también puede ser importante si se desea migrar.

jQuery Mobile es el menos popular de los 3, además es el menos actualizado (ver github) y me atrevo a asegurar que el menos utilizado. Conozco jQuery Mobile desde su creación y nunca he visto un proyecto que lo utilice, ni un solo programador (ni siquiera los más malos y perezosos que he conocido) que lo proponga en cualquier etapa de un proyecto.